# How does a Joy-Con know what color it is?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-switch, system-mods

When signing in to a Nintendo Switch using Joy Cons, the screen will always show the color for them. But, how does it know? In terms of parts, all Joy-Cons seem just about interchangeable?

More importantly, can a user potentially change what color a Joy Con thinks it is?

Comment: It looks deep inside itself, then remembers the colour is on the outside, and looks there instead.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

When the Joy Con connects to the Nintendo Switch via Bluetooth, it sends some data as a "handshake" between the console and the controller. In this data, the Joy Con itself reports the HEX Color and Side (L/R) of the controller.

This can be confirmed with a program called [Joy-Con Toolkit](https://gbatemp.net/threads/tool-joy-con-toolkit.478560/) that allows you to see and change the colors reported by the individual controllers just by connecting them via Bluetooth:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108990/discussion-on-answer-by-lemon-how-does-a-joy-con-know-what-color-it-is).